# SPFieldUserValue and UserProfileManager / Convert UserProfile to SPFieldUserValue

Tags: user-profile

I have a big problem. I would like add a user to a list item via  SPFieldUserValue. But this user has never used the Sharepoint site before. So I can not select the SPUser-Object of this user from a SPUserCollection.

With the UserProfileManager I can select the profile of the user but I can not convert this profile to a SPFieldUserValue.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SPWeb.EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) that'll make sure the user exist on the site

Comment: Great it works :-)

Comment: Snippet of my solution

$upm =  New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

$AllProfiles = $upm.GetEnumerator()
foreach($profile in $AllProfiles){
$accountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value
$lookupUser = $web.EnsureUser($accountName)
}